# PHP/AJAX Login taking very long

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I've inherited a website that requires users to login too.

The login uses Ajax and PHP only this login procedure can take up to a minute to complete when there is only 4000 users registered.

Could this be due to the way the login is coded?

**AJAX**

```
 <form name="login-form" onsubmit="return false">
            <input type="text" id="the_username" value="Username" onfocus="emptyUsername(this);" onblur="clickrecall(this,'Username')"  class="focusfield input push"  />
            <input type="password" id="the_password" value="Password" class="input" onfocus="emptyPassword(this);" onblur="clickrecall(this,'Password')" /> 
            <span id="dialog-login-fail" title="Login failed"></span>
            <input type="submit" onclick="javascript:void(0);"  id="loginBtnBre" class="sign-in signin-submit-btn" value="Login Now" /> 
 </form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
require 'config.inc.php';

foreach($_POST as $k=>$v) 
{
$_POST[$k] = trim($v);
}

if(!isset($_POST['theusername']) or !isset($_POST['thepassword']))
{
    print "Please use all fields";
}elseif(empty($_POST['theusername'])){
    print "Please enter a username";
}elseif(empty($_POST['thepassword'])){
    print "Please enter a password";
}elseif($_POST['theusername'] == "username" && $_POST['thepassword'] == "password")
{
    print "Password & User cannot be the ones already listed";
}elseif(!preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]+$/i", $_POST['theusername']))
{
    print "Please use only characters and numbers for username, no spaces, dashes or others!";
}else{

    $password = md5($_POST['thepassword']);
    $user = $_POST['theusername'];

    $loginVar = $usersClass->login($user, $password);

    if(is_array($loginVar))
    {
        $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = $loginVar; 
        @session_regenerate_id(true);

        print "success";

    }else{
        print "Whoops, something went wrong! Try again.";
    }
}

?>
```

Query

```
public function login($username, $password)
{

    $rs = mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`active` from `$this->usersTable` WHERE 
        `username` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."' AND 
        `password` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."'");

    if($rs) {
        $row = @mysql_fetch_object($rs);

            return $this->userInfo($row->id);

    }else{
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Its more likely to be the backend database code.  Post the code for `$usersClass->login` and if there is any sql in there, post the results of `explain <that sql>`

Comment: I'd rather say that if there are only 4000 users in the database, you're missing an index in there. Another possibility is a bad SQL query.

Comment: If you disable javasript in your browser is login still takes a long time? Show us your JS code.

Answer (score 1):

First change the browser to make sure that it's not a problem with the browser (rare, yet still happens sometimes).

Then try a PHP profiler to identify the "slow" backend code. There is even a nice tutorial at http://erichogue.ca/2011/03/linux/profiling-a-php-application/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the firebug feature of the firefox to know if the correct information is being posted or not? I can see that there is no problem except a "login" function.
You can echo the query and copy it from firebug and run it to the database. 
Track the time it takes to run that query and add some second on it. See if your database query takes lots of time or not.

If your query takes more time then you need to optimize your SQL query

Answer (score 0):

You probably dont have an index on the username or password fields

Run:

```
alter table `TableName` add index `username` (`username`(500));
alter table `TableName` add index `password` (`password`(500));
```

From a mysql prompt, where TableName is the name of your table, then try again.  If that speeds things up, adjust the indexes to be a more suitable length.

And you really shouldn't be storing passwords as clear text in the database.  As bare minimum store them as hashed strings (MD5 etc) or better yet, store them as salted MD5 hashes.

I would change your select to just select based on the username (drop the password) then perform additional checks to make sure the password entered matches that of the returned row.